# I need to increase the Maximum possible array size

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory

I have a 4GB Ram installed on Coure2Duo PC with a 32bit Windows 7 Operating system. I have increased the paging size up to 106110MB. But after doing all this I am not able to significantly increase the maximum array size.

Following are the specs

```
memory
Maximum possible array:             129 MB (1.348e+08 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:    732 MB (7.673e+08 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:              563 MB (5.899e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):             3549 MB (3.722e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.
```

Kindly help me on your earliest. I am not even able to read a file of 48+MB size in double format.

Comment: that's a question for super user SE

Comment: Daft question perghaps, but do you really need those huge arrays? Can you work on chunks instead or change your algorithm?

Comment: I seriousl;y think the specs are good enough for my usage but some how they don't let me load any file bigger than 50MB in double format. just trying to figure out what's the issue.

Comment: @Robocop No, it's a question for stackoverflow because it directly involves a tool for programming, and because the answer has implications for how to programmatically manage memory in MATLAB.

Answer (score 3):

There are two things you can do to clear up memory for MATLAB.  Since you're using a 32-bit version of the program, you're normally limited to 2GB of memory.  Using the [`/3GB` switch](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/03/23/memory-management-demystifying-3gb.aspx) while opening the program makes an additional 1GB of RAM available to that program.

Second, you should consider using the [`pack()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pack.html) function, which rearranges variables in RAM to free up more `contiguous` memory space.  This, more than anything, is affecting your ability to open individual arrays.

Remember: you can figure out how many items an array will hold by dividing the memory amount available by the size of the variable type.  `Double` variables take up 8 bytes each.  Your 129MB of space available should allow around 16.85 million `double` values in a single array.

You can view information about memory usage using the [memory functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/memory.html) included in MATLAB.

- `memory` shows the memory information
- `inmem` will show you the variables and functions stored in memory
- `clear` will allow you to clear the memory of specific variables or functions.

Comment: Ah, this brings back old memories.  Once I switched to 64-bit Windows+MATLAB, I never looked back.  Way better memory management.

Comment: @philopthegreat  clear is not clearing the mmeory, it do clear a variable from the workspcae but it does not free up the space from the memory. Any suggestion on that or it jsut my pc

Answer (score 0):

You may try to set the [3GB switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff556232.aspx), maybe this increases the possible memory. Otherwise: Switch to a 64 bit os. Your system wastes 547MB of RAM simply because there are no addresses for it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. don't you think specs like these are more than enough to support a 60 MB file. I don't know why are they not letting me load such a small file. I have monitored the task manager and physical memory don't show its fulll usage. some thing is wrong with the settings. can you guide me what stuff do Ineed to check or what might me etting wrong

Comment: Your array size is limited by the contiguous address space. There is enough free physical memory, but the free addresses are fragmented.

Comment: @chappjc I have used the pack command, but it does not clear the memory

Comment: >> memory
a=rand(4000,4000);
b=rand(4000,4000);
c=a*b;
clear all
Maximum possible array:   1000 MB (1.048e+09 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:   1331 MB (1.395e+09 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:    426 MB (4.463e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   3549 MB (3.722e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.

Comment: >>pack
>>memory
Maximum possible array:    624 MB (6.544e+08 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:   1299 MB (1.362e+09 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:    456 MB (4.782e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   3549 MB (3.722e+09 bytes)

*  Limited by contiguous virtual address space available.
** Limited by virtual address space available.

Comment: @DanielR "clear all" is also not working, I mean its not clearing up the memory, it do get escaped from the workspace but memory don't get back :(